# how to get the queue number from queued ado pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

tried api to get the queue number from the queued azure devops pipeline.
by using this queue , i want to scale up and down the agents in ec2 machine.
or scale ec2 machines in autoscaling group.
Your thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Current, there is no Rest API can directly get all queued Pipeline job from Azure Pipeline.

Based on your requirement, you need to check the number of queued Pipeline jobs to add ec2 machines.

I suggest that you can check all Agent jobs in Agent pools with the Rest API:

```
Get https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{PoolID}/jobrequests?api-version=5.1
```

Then you can check the **assignTime** value in the API Response to confirm if the Pipeline job is queued.

Here is the PowerShell script:

```
$token = "PAT"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$Agentpools= poolid1,poolid2

$Count= 0

foreach($poolid in $Agentpools)
{

    $url="https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/$($poolid)/jobrequests?api-version=5.1"

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json
    

    foreach($Jobinfo in $response.value)
    {

      if($Jobinfo.assignTime -eq $Null)
      {
        echo $jobinfo.requestId
        $Count = $Count + 1

      }
    }

}

echo "QueueJobNumber: $Count"
```

You can get the Poolid in **Organization Settings -> Agent Pools -> Select Agent Pool** and check the URL.

For example:

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

[image]